# Does full calendar have to re-render every event after an external event is dropped on the calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm building a calendar that allows users to drag external events onto the calendar. When they do this an ajax call fires of and saves the event to the database. In order to understand what event is then resized or indeed rescheduled i update the event with the id of the event ive just created in the database. This means that if i need to further update the event. i.e someone moves the event or indeed changes the duration etc i can fire of the id with another ajax call and update the event.

The issue is that each time an event is dropped on the calendar, every event seems to re-render wiping out the id's that id added to each event. Are there any ways to prevent a full re-render? or a way to preserve id's on the element? you can see below i add the id occurance-387 to the html however when i add another event this gets wiped out. Any help would be appreciated! :-)

```
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end  fc-draggable fc-resizable _fc4" id="occurance-387"><div class="fc-content"> <span class="fc-title">A Very Short Introduction to… Anxiety</span></div><div class="fc-resizer"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your id to the html.  You should be storing your id as a property in the *eventObject*.  Then, when you need to update your database, you can get the id out of the *eventObject*.

```
eventResize: function(event){
    $.ajax('http://myendpoint.com/?saveNewEndDate", {id:event.id,newEndTime: event.end.format()},function(data){
        if(data) {alert('Success!');}
    });
}
```

There are other variables passed to the function that could be useful: delta, revertFunc.  Check the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) for details.

In my implementation, anytime a new event is saved to the calendar with *drop* callback function, my ajax response returns a json representation of a calendar *eventObject* and then I call renderEvent method to add it to the calendar.  My json event object contains an id property.

```
$(#calendarContainer').fullCalendar('renderEvent', results.calendarEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks thats really useful. However how do i store the id in the event object. The drop event callback doesnt seem to have created the event rather the eventAfterRender method? would you mind posting a full example if possible?

Comment: dont worry, daft question worked it out, thanks so much, simple answer works a treat. :-)